# is there a text editor which does not change the list of recent files?

Tags: gedit, text-editor

I am using 18.04

Sometimes I am editing a text file in gedit when I have to lookup and copy from other text files. Doing that in gedit will fill up the list of recent files with these other files, making the history unusable.

Is there any way to lookup and edit text without affecting the history for gedit?

Comment: Any time you even open the file it is always added to the recents list.  You can though use a different editor to open the other files in, or `cat` them to the screen in a terminal for copying and pasting from.

Comment: Unfortunately, using another text editor does not help. The opened file also goes into the list recent files regardless which editor is used.

Comment: I actually use `mousepad` in Xubuntu, and it is installable in other DEs.  It has its own recent file list instead of sharing like the other editors do.  It may not be as fancy, but I think it might do the job.  So, if you open something in `mousepad` then something in `gedit`, the file opened in `gedit` does not show up in the `mousepad` recently opened list.  I am not aware of any of the graphical editors that don't add to the recently opened list.  `sudo apt install mousepad`

Comment: In a first try I found: Despite mousepad has its own recent file list, the files edited in mousepad also show up in gedit's recent file list. I'll try the other way round later.

Comment: Try using `featherpad` as the second editor. It's qt-based but doesn't bring in too many dependencies. Gedit;s recent files list doesn't to be affected by opening another file in featherpad and copying stuff from there into the file opened in gedit.

Comment: I guess gtk3 (and possibly even gtk2) editors share the same `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` whereas `qt` editors don't. A totally different way is to use something like `ranger` which is a multi-pane "file manager" to identify and preview files you wish to copy from into your opened gedit document: by default, ranger will probably open text files in `nano` in its third and you can copy from there into gedit without affecting gedit's recently used list.

Comment: Another example for a Qt text editor which will not use `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` is "kate". Note that "kate" uses KDE.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli the reason I didn't mention Kate (or even KWrite) (although I use Kate in my Kubuntu) is it will bring in far more KDE-dependencies than Featherpad. Also, it appears that OP wants to use the program in a very limited way. So, the simpler the editor, the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To look into this, I tested a

- a combination of`mousepad` (the default editor in Xubuntu) and `gedit`, and also
- a combination of `featherpad` (a `qt-based` text editor) and `gedit`.

I found that text files opened and edited and then closed in `featherpad` did **not** affect the *recent files* list of `gedit`. However, performing a similar exercise with `mousepad` directly affected the *recent files* list of `gedit`.

You can see this by running

```
watch ls -l ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

and looking for a change in file size. Merely opening a text file with `gedit` or `mousepad` affects the file size of `recently-used.xbel`. Doing the same with `featherpad` has no effect; `recently-used.xbel` is not altered in any way.

Just to be clear, both `gedit` and `mousepad` access `recently-used.xbel` to build their respective (but same) recent files list. `featherpad` does not. So you can safely use a combination of `gedit` and `featherpad`

One fear among some users is the number of dependencies pulled in by installing a `qt`-based application. You can gauge that for yourself with a simulation, no `sudo` required because nothing is actually done:

```
apt install -s featherpad
```

In a relatively vanilla Ubuntu **20**.04 VM, a total of 16 packages (10.9 MB archives) would be installed, and 47.1 MB disk space would be utilized.

There is also the concern, expressed by some, of the RAM "consumption" by having two toolkits loaded.

Obviously, if these concerns are matter, the use of `featherpad`
 is out of the question. Maybe `nano` could be the secondary editor.

If the use of `nano` is acceptable, then also consider the terminal-based file manager `ranger` which makes it very, very easy to move around (Miller columns!), preview a variety of file types, and to easily access text files with `nano`.

Comment: I also tried Mousepad, Notepadqq and Kate (via flatpak). The only one which does not affect the Gedit history is Featherpad. So, Featherpad is the solution, I mark the answer as accepted. Thank you very much!

Comment: I didn't think of looking at snaps or (flatpaks)! Given their "confinements", I'm surprised they still affected Gedit's recent history.